# Why does this insert into database without http:// but not insert with the http://

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I need to insert a site_title, site_address (the url) site_description & site_category into my database from the front-end with jquery/json.. It inserts the site and updates the frontend fine if I do not put the "http://" in the site_address input field but as soon as I do, it will not inster to the database..

I have this code

**FORM IN HOME VIEW:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="addsite_form">
  <input id="account_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('account_id');?>"/>
  <label for="site_title"><strong>Site Name:</strong></label> 
  <input id="site_title" type="text" maxLength="25" tabindex="1" name="site_title" /> 
  <label for="site_address"><strong>Site Address:</strong></label> 
  <input id="site_address" type="text" tabindex="2" name="site_address" /> 
  <label for="site_description"><strong>Site Description:</strong></label> 
  <input id="site_description" type="text" tabindex="3" name="site_description" /> 
  <label for="site_category"><strong>Site Category:</strong></label> 
  <input id="site_category" type="text" tabindex="4" name="site_category" /> 

  <input id="addsite_form_submit" type="submit" value="Add Site" name="submit" tabindex="5" /> 

</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function addUserSites() {

  $account_id = $this->input->post('account_id');
  $site_title = $this->input->post('site_title');
  $site_description = $this->input->post('site_description');
  $site_address = $this->input->post('site_address');
  $site_category = $this->input->post('site_category');

  $array = array(
    'account_id' => $account_id,
    'site_title' => $site_title,
    'site_description' => $site_description,
    'site_address' => $site_address,
    'site_category' => $site_category,

  );

  echo json_encode($this->usersites_model->insertsites($array));

}
```

**MODEL:**

```
public function insertsites($data)  {

  $this->db->insert('usersites', $data);

  return TRUE; 

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.addsite_form').submit(function() {
  var account_id = $("#account_id").val();
  var site_title = $("#site_title").val();
  var site_address = $("#site_address").val();
  var site_description = $("#site_description").val();
  var site_category = $("#site_category").val();

  $.post("/usersites/addusersites", { 

    "account_id" : account_id,
    "site_title" : site_title, 
    "site_address" : site_address, 
    "site_description" : site_description, 
    "site_category" : site_category, 
  },

  function(data){
  }, "json");
});
```

**EDIT** - **SOLUTION**

Firstly, let me say a big thank you to **Marshall Brekka** who suggested the encodeURIComponent.. I have now read up on it and found the php version..

I have added urlencode to my controller and it now works.. here is the new controller

```
    public function addUserSites() {

    $account_id = $this->input->post('account_id');
    $site_title = $this->input->post('site_title');
    $site_description = $this->input->post('site_description');
    $site_address = $this->input->post(urlencode('site_address'));//added urlencode
    $site_category = $this->input->post('site_category');

    $array = array(
        'account_id' => $account_id,
        'site_title' => $site_title,
        'site_description' => $site_description,
        'site_address' => $site_address,
        'site_category' => $site_category,

    );

  echo json_encode($this->usersites_model->insertsites($array));

}
```

May I also say that I think that the people who have down voted my questions, no matter how high they stand in the stack overflow community need to get out more! I am a noob, I am still learning, I cannot afford to go to uni to learn this, I sometimes need help.. Were you never at that stage? Pffft!

Comment: Why did you edit the question Jakub??

Comment: Also, why did you vote the question down??

Comment: Jakub improved your question. See [this section of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Comment: You can look at his Jakub's edits yourself by just clicking on the place where it says it was edited.  They look mostly like cleaning up code indentation, fixing tags and removing stuff that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thats why I do not understand.. "Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated." It now sounds as though I am being blunt.. All of my Civility has been removed.. :(

Comment: "Civility" means "not rude". It doesn't mean that you have to fill the question with chatter. Bluntness is encouraged.

Comment: @DanielCheeseman You should encode all inputs -- this will help protect against (but not stop) XSS attacks.  Also what happens when someone names their site `this is a \\ bad // site name` as an example of input that would crash your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you have not url encoded your values, try this.

```
$.post("/usersites/addusersites", { 

    "account_id" : account_id,
    "site_title" : site_title, 
    "site_address" : encodeURIComponent(site_address), 
    "site_description" : site_description, 
    "site_category" : site_category, 
},
```

Comment: Thanks but did not work.. It is really strange, if I do not fill out the other inputs bar the site address input and fill it with http://examplesite.com it works.. then as soon as I fill out the other inputs, it does not work again.. Thank you for your time.